# Site is returning ArgumentOutOfRangeException when automating a search using javascript

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I'm trying to automate a search on an [airline website](http://www.cebupacificair.com/) using javascript. I'm changing the values of the search form's elements and perform a search button click.

```
javascript:
document.getElementById("txtFromSingle").value = 'Sydney (SYD)';
document.getElementById("txtToSingle").value = 'Hong Kong (HKG)';
document.getElementById("txtDepartureDateSingle").value = '8 Nov 2014';
document.getElementById("txtReturnDateSingle").value = '8 Dec 2014';
document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-alt btn-block btn-large find-it")[0].click();
```

This is my js code and if you run it on the search flight page, the site returns ERROR [5022: ArgumentOutOfRangeException] but will work if you do a normal search with the same values.

I also noticed when you perform a select of any orgin and destination and run this code, it will work. It's really weird.

Answer (score 0):

The page is doing something else when you select the things on the panel. You can't just fill the inputs with some text. Obviously the page is setting up some variables that, once the button "Find It" gets clicked, are sent to the server.